Does the Alveolar Tap Cause Complete Closure of the Vocal Tract and Total Obstruction of the Airstream for a Short Time?
When doing the alveolar tap, does the tongue tip cause complete occlusion in the vocal tract and total obstruction of the airflow for a split second? If so, then how long does the blockage of air last, and does this mean that an alveolar tap is essentially a brief stop or plosive caused by a single, rapid movement confined to the tongue tip?

I would say it’s possible to produce an alveolar tap either with or without full closure. I don’t think there are any languages that actually distinguish the two (at least not that I’ve heard of), and they are acoustically very close to one another. I would guess that in regular speech, it’s more common typologically not to have a complete closure, since closure (a) takes slightly more muscle work, and (b) reduces the acoustic difference with [d]. The only case I can think of where closure is the norm is Japanese.
